# Trying to webscrape data from a table and bs4 gives None though value is there

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the Fantasy Football Games Week data for each player, and my beautifulsoup (playerStatTable) keeps returing 'None' even though the correct elements have been selected.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/statistics'
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()#catch errors
print(res.status_code)

playerSoup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

playerStatTable = playerSoup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'Table-ziussd-1 ElementDialog__HistoryTable-gmefnd-16 hraaSw'})

print(playerStatTable)

#if playerStatTable is not None:
for gw in playerStatTable.find_all("tbody"):
    rows = gw.find_all('tr')
```

I am pretty much a beginner and really need to get the hang of using requests and beautiful soup.
A screenshot can be seen below. Thank you for your help.

[image: Screenshot of the web page and html elements]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see on the page is rendered dynamically via JavaScript. You can use `selenium` to extract data or use `requests`/`json` to load the data directly from their API. For example:

```
import json
import requests 


url = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/'
ajax_url = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/element-summary/{}/'

data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for e in data['elements']:
    print(e['first_name'], e['second_name'])
    player_data = requests.get(ajax_url.format(e['id'])).json()
    
    # uncomment this to print all player data:
    # print(json.dumps(player_data, indent=4))    

    # print only first row from history:
    print(json.dumps(player_data['history'][0], indent=4))

    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Mesut Özil
{
    "element": 1,
    "fixture": 2,
    "opponent_team": 8,
    "total_points": 0,
    "was_home": false,
    "kickoff_time": "2020-09-12T11:30:00Z",
    "team_h_score": 0,
    "team_a_score": 3,
    "round": 1,
    "minutes": 0,
    "goals_scored": 0,
    "assists": 0,
    "clean_sheets": 0,
    "goals_conceded": 0,
    "own_goals": 0,
    "penalties_saved": 0,
    "penalties_missed": 0,
    "yellow_cards": 0,
    "red_cards": 0,
    "saves": 0,
    "bonus": 0,
    "bps": 0,
    "influence": "0.0",
    "creativity": "0.0",
    "threat": "0.0",
    "ict_index": "0.0",
    "value": 70,
    "transfers_balance": 0,
    "selected": 76656,
    "transfers_in": 0,
    "transfers_out": 0
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sokratis Papastathopoulos
{
    "element": 2,
    "fixture": 2,
    "opponent_team": 8,
    "total_points": 0,
    "was_home": false,
    "kickoff_time": "2020-09-12T11:30:00Z",
    "team_h_score": 0,
    "team_a_score": 3,
    "round": 1,
    "minutes": 0,
    "goals_scored": 0,
    "assists": 0,
    "clean_sheets": 0,
    "goals_conceded": 0,
    "own_goals": 0,
    "penalties_saved": 0,
    "penalties_missed": 0,
    "yellow_cards": 0,
    "red_cards": 0,
    "saves": 0,
    "bonus": 0,
    "bps": 0,
    "influence": "0.0",
    "creativity": "0.0",
    "threat": "0.0",
    "ict_index": "0.0",
    "value": 50,
    "transfers_balance": 0,
    "selected": 12184,
    "transfers_in": 0,
    "transfers_out": 0
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you! this has helped a lot!!
I can carry on with my scraping with the code provided above and I will make an effort to get comfortable with selenium as well.

Thanks For The Help.